# Why can't my laptop connect to one specific wifi router?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, connection, router

I am trying to connect to my workplace network. The network and the wifi is working fine for all other devices. My laptop could also connect to it in the past, and it has no problem connecting to other routers.

Now, I don't even see it in the list.

I have found similar questions about this problem, but the solution was unclear for me. The root of the problem might be something about the router sign frequency, but I can't mess with the router.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Laptop: eMachines eME528

Comment: Unfortunately there is not enough information here to help with a solution. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re running (1) the brand/model of your computer (2) the aspects of solutions you’ve tried but are unclear. With this, it may be possible to offer an answer 

Comment: Have you changed the DNS settings in your laptop? I know I had trouble connecting to my hotel's "captive portal" until I set the DNS back to default.